# Run ISV Hammer on Package Versions and Subscriber Orgs

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, subscriber

We are trying to run ISV Hammer tests with our new package version against subscriber org based on a new feature available in Winter 20 (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_isvforce_isvhammer.htm).

We've already enabled Dev Hub and registered package namespace in subscriber org.
But still when trying to run hammer tests we are getting back an error:
`Your org doesn't have permission to run ISV Hammer.`

`sfdx force:package:hammertest:run -u packageMain --packageversionids 04txxx --subscriberorgs 00Dxxx`

Is there any additional configuration required, e.g. opening case in support etc.? Seems like this feature is in beta already, not a pilot anymore.

Any help would be appreciated